# Error Inserting Data into Table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values into my `employee` table using MySQL.

**My code**

```
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, NULL, NULL);
```

**The error**

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, ' at line 5
```

It will not allow me to enter any data into the employee table.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Post the table definition

Comment: The error would imply that there's some code *before* this.  Maybe some non-printable character got in there in a bad copy/paste?

Comment: This is the table:                                                                                      'CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40),
    birth_day DATE,
    sex VARCHAR (1),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
    brand_id INT
);'

Comment: There is nüthing wrong with your table or insert. Clear evrything and type in everything in new. sometimes the are characters that are nit dispaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this general example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

In your case you didn't mentioned all the columns, which is fine, if you are inserting values for all columns. Would be interesting to see your table.

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40),
    birth_day DATE,
    sex VARCHAR (1),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
    brand_id INT
);'

Comment: @BrandonCruz I run that on my own database server and everything worked fine. Insert and create table works

Answer (score 0):

I think You are getting an error on the date value, so instead you can use `to_date('1967-11-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD');` or instead, you can also use **date datatype** as `date '1967-11-17'` it will work fine for both of them.

I know it's way too late, you might have figured it out already. Still, I'm replying coz it might be helpful for someone who is stuck at the same point. Hope This helps.